# touched property not set to true if I upload file

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form and I use formik to control it , all the inputs when changed the touched property is not set to true when the file upload and the name of the file change, and validate function is not called.

Is there any solution ?

````
                                        <Form.Control
                                            type="text"
                                            name="paramDefaultValue"
                                            id="paramDefaultValue"
                                            onChange={handleChangeparamDefaultValue(
                                                values,
                                                i,
                                                param.paramId,
                                                setFieldValue
                                            )}
                                            value={param.paramDefaultValue}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            placeholder="Valeur par défaut"
                                        />

                                        <Form.Control
                                            id="fileToUpload"
                                            name="paramDefaultValue"
                                            type="file"
                                            accept={param.paramDefaultValue.name === 'Fichier CSV'}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                                            onChange={
                                                onFileChange(values,
                                                    i,
                                                    param.paramId,
                                                    setFieldValue,
                                                    true
                                                )}
                                        />
                                    </>```
````

Comment: Instead of calling functions directly in `onChange={handleChangeparamDefaultValue(...)}` you should pass a callback function:   `onChange={() => handleChangeparamDefaultValue(...)}`

Comment: @EnfieldLi Unfortunately the solution doesn't work